# R ggplot for loop aes variable

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a data frame `dat` that I am trying to plot with a for loop. The reason why I'm using a forloop in a function to plot ggplots is because I would like to call this function many times later.

```
> head(dat)
      tpl     motif strand base score ipdRatio
1:  24501 AAGTACTCG      0    A    51    3.108
2:  58809 GAGTACTAC      0    A    69    4.095
3:  65614 TAGTACTCA      0    A    61    3.341
4:  78494 GAGTACTAC      0    A    92    4.968
5:  92127 AAGTACTTA      0    A    23    1.702
6: 193102 GAGTACTCG      0    A    96    5.255
```

I continue getting an error:

> Error in eval(as.symbol(x_val)) : 
>     error in evaluating the argument 'expr' in selecting a method for function 'eval': Error in as.symbol(x_val) : object 'x_val' not found

When I try calling the function like so:

```
plotme <- function(dataf,x_val,bin_width){
  print(ggplot(dataf, aes(x = eval(as.symbol(x_val)))) +
          geom_histogram(binwidth = bin_width))
}

ratioplot <- plotme(dat,"ipdRatio",.5)
```

Any suggestions on what might be causing the error here?

Comment: Anything you put inside `aes()` should exist in the data.frame you feed `ggplot()` with.

Comment: but column `ipdRatio` exists in `dat` dataframe

Comment: But not `x_val`, as said in the error message.

Comment: Can x_val not be variable that I can read into the function, because I'm calling it in `aes()`? I ask this because I'm planning to create histograms with x values at different columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution, I simply had to use `aes_string` instead of `aes` to call in variable aes column values.

Like so:

```
plotme <- function(dataf,x_val,bin_width){
  print(ggplot(dataf, aes_string(x = x_val)) +
          geom_histogram(binwidth = bin_width))
}

ratioplot <- plotme(dat,"ipdRatio",15)
```

Comment: You can go ahead and check this to indicate the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

First of, I prefer the `aes()` over `aes_string` and then just do

```
if (is.character(x_val)) {x_val <- which(names(dataf) == x_val)}
```

That way you can call it as numeric or as character when refering to the column.

Secondly, there is a something wrong with the function you have made.

try and clear your workspeace entirely, and run this this:

```
dat <- data.frame(ipdRatio=rnorm(100));library(ggplot2)

plotme <- function(dataf,x_val,bin_width){
        localEnv <- environment()
        if (is.character(x_val)) {x_val <- which(names(dataf) == x_val)}
        print(ggplot(dataf, aes(x = dataf[,x_val])) +
                      geom_histogram(binwidth = bin_width))
}

ratioplot <- plotme(dataf=dat,"ipdRatio",.5)
```

would return

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'dataf' not found
```

The function call dataf=dat is simply not being made, and the reason it works for you now is because you have dataf in your global environment.

to change the function to specify the environment as local

```
dat <- data.frame(ipdRatio=rnorm(100));

plotme <- function(dataf,x_val,bin_width){
        localEnv <- environment()
        if (is.character(x_val)) {x_val <- which(names(dataf) == x_val)}
        print(ggplot(dataf, aes(x = dataf[,x_val]),environment=localEnv) +
                      geom_histogram(binwidth = bin_width))
}

ratioplot <- plotme(dataf=dat,"ipdRatio",.5)
```

Comment: Your original function and the function in @Chani's answer run fine for me without needing the addition of an `environment` argument.  And I definitely don't have anything named `datadf` floating around my environment...

Comment: `dataf` - okay maybe it is just my specific error, but with a clean global environment, and without specifiying env in the function i get an error.